# Fix error message for install a babel plugin

Tags: reactjs, plugins, babeljs, node-modules, babel-plugin

I'm trying to fix an error message that instructs me to install a Babel plugin. I've done that, but the error message still persists. I'm not making any progress with ChatGPT either. Does anyone have any further suggestions?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdIRT.png)

{
"presets": [
"@babel/preset-env",
"@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
"@babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment"
]
}